# Multivariate Gaussian vs univariate

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

I am developing a classification task where I generate a gaussian distribution (its mean and standard deviation) from a set of 3-dimensional data. My question is: would the classifier give same outputs if I use three uni variate normal distributions or one 3-dimensional multivariate distribution? When getting the probability of a test point belonging to either the 3D distribution or the three separate distributions, would the number be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3-d multivariate distribution would be the same as the 3 independent 1-d distributions if, you guessed, the dimensions are statistically independent of each other.  If they are correlated, then you have to introduce that correlation one way or another.